# On meromorphic continuation of zeta function(s) and special values at negative integers

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

Euler developped (at least) two different approaches in order to calculate the values $\zeta(-m)$ of the zeta function $$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^s}$$ at non-positive integers.

In one approach Euler obtained the following formula for the zeta function $$\zeta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} (-1)^i \frac1{(i+1)^s} $$
by applying the so called Euler transformation to the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac1{(n+1)^s}$ (see for example the Wiki article [Euler summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation)).

One great advantage of this formula is that you can immediately calculate the values at the negative integers because the infinite series reduces to a finite sum in this case.

Moreover this formula gives at the same time a meromorphic continuation of the zeta functions to the complex plane!

In another approach Euler introduced a formal parameter $t$ and showed that $$(1-2^{m+1})\zeta(-m) = (t \frac{d}{dt})^m(\frac{t}{t+1})|_{t=1} = (\frac d {dx})^m(\frac{e^x}{1+e^x})| _{x=0} $$ This is for example described in the very nice book of Hida "Elementary theory of L-functions and Eisenstein series".
Further, this approach could be generalized to "L-functions of totally real number fields" by Shintani, Cassou-Nouges and others (see again Hida's book, e.g.).

My questions are now the following:

> 1) Can the first approach described above generalized to other 
>   Dedekind zeta functions? I completely lack an understanding of the Euler 
>   transformation. Is there a way to "understand" Euler's formula 
>   for the zeta function in a broader sense?
>
> 2) The Riemannian approach to the meromorphic continuation of the zeta function is based on looking at the Mellin transformation of Jacobi's $\theta$-function. It is well known, by the work of Hecke, that this approach generalizes to arbitrary Hecke L-functions. On the other hand, with this approach the information about the special values at non-positive integers of the corresponding Hecke L-function are more difficult to reveal (at least as far as I know). (EDIT: I'm aware of the fact, that calculating special values is extremely hard and one of the big challenges in number theory, I just try to understand certain structures underlying this more than beautiful area of mathematics...)

This makes we wondering whether there is a relation between the approaches of Euler and Riemann to the meromorphic continuation of the zeta function.

```
Is there a "principle" that relates Euler's analytic continuation to Riemann's ?
```

(One major difference is of course that Euler's expression doesn't involve the archimedean factor at all! I also lack a real understanding on why the archimedean Euler factor appears in Riemann's approach.)

```
3) Is there a known relation between the two different approaches of Euler for 
calculating the values $\zeta(-m)$? Should one expect one?
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

In partial answer to 2), one can in fact get information about special values of $L$-functions via theta series.  See, for example, Villegas and Zagier's paper "Square roots of central values of Hecke L-series" in the book Advances in Number Theory.  (Disclaimer: I'm no expert,and it's certainly a lot more complex than Euler's approach to special values of $\zeta(s)$.)